# Conditional Constraint on field level

Tags: oracle

I have a table 'TEST' with 2 columns as shown below :

```
create table TEST (
SEQ_NUM NUMBER NOT NULL,
SWITCH VARCHAR2(1))
```

The switch column receives input as either 0 or 1 from the Application.
For a particular SEQ_NUM value we can have any number of rows with Switch value 0.
But for a particular SEQ_NUM value, we can only have one record with SWITCH value 1.

I have tried creating such constraint, but it is throwing syntax errors:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX EMP_INDEX
ON TEST(
(CASE
     WHEN SWITCH = 1
         THEN UNIQUE (SEQ_NUM)        
     ELSE
         NULL
 END));
```

To be more clear, the output should be as below:

> SQL> insert into TEST(SEQ_NUM,SWITCH) values (3,0);
>   SQL> 1 row created.
>
> SQL> insert into TEST(SEQ_NUM,SWITCH) values (3,0);
>   SQL> 1 row created.

---

> SQL> insert into TEST(SEQ_NUM,SWITCH) values (3,1);
>   SQL> 1 row created.
>
> SQL> insert into TEST(SEQ_NUM,SWITCH) values (3,1);
>
> ORA-error : query insertion failed with xyz error ---- query should throw error if I insert second time.

Comment: Thank you so much!! It was really very helpful :)  I missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `UNIQUE` from the CASE expression:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX EMP_INDEX
  ON TEST(CASE WHEN SWITCH = 1 THEN SEQ_NUM ELSE NULL END);
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d3ac889aa5127bb2511cb4db611f4981